# WP All Export and WP All Import - Woocommerce product bundles?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, export, bundles

Please help - Woocommerce Product Bundle import-export via WP All Import and WP All Export

I use WP All Export and WP All Import plugins, and the Woocommerce Product Bundles too (https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/). I want the import-export plugin to be able to handle product bundles for bulk editing. How? I spent hours reading, I couldn't find a solution.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: You can check [this plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/import-export-suite-for-woocommerce/) that supports bundle products.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but my client use the WP All import plugin, it would be important to solve it using that product